# Get every n number of elements in list Flutter Dart

Tags: dart

I have a list of elements and I need to get a list containing the first element followed by every `n`th element afterwards. For example: given  `n = 3` and the list `[banana, cherry, apple, pear, kiwi]`, I need to get the list `[banana, pear]`. I need this regardless of specific content, since the list depends on user input.

How do I do this using Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart has a great set of [collection operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators) that make this type of problem pretty straightforward to solve. For example, we could do something like:

```dart
extension X<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> everyNth(int n) => [for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i += n) this[i]];
}

main() {
  final fruit = ["banana", "cherry", "apple", "pear", "kiwi"];
  print(fruit.everyNth(3));
}
```

Output:

```
[banana, pear]
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You may access list in dart by providing an index like for example:

```
List<String> fruits = ["banana","cherry","apple","pear","kiwi"];
print(fruits[0]); // Will print to the console "banana";
```

On your case, you are trying to access index 0 and index 3 which is "banana" and "pear".

You may create a function that accepts an index like:

```
String getFruit(int index, List<String> fruits) => fruits[index];
print(getFruit[0]); // Will print "banana";
```

or if you need to actually get the specific ranges you may use:

```
List<String> fruits =["banana","cherry","apple","pear","kiwi"].getRange(0,4);
// Will give you "banana","cherry","apple","pear
```

You may check : https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/List-class.html for more information.

Edited answer based off the comment:

```
List<String> getElements(List userInput, nIndex){
 List elements = [];
 for(int x = 0; x<userInput.length;x++){
  if(x % nIndex == 0){
   elements.add(userInput[x]);
  }
 }
 return elements;
}

List fruits = ["banana","cherry","apple","pear","kiwi"];
print(getElements(fruits,2));
```

or you may try to look and use `List.retainWhere()` depending on your use case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but that's not the issue. I can get the specific range but  what I want is : regardless of the length of the list (which is dependent on user input), get every n elements.

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope this helps you on your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension method, which will work on lists of any type:

```
 extension GetEveryN<T> on List<T> {
  List<T> elementsEveryN(int n) {
    List<T> result = [];
    for(int index = 0; index < length; index +=1) {
      if(index % n == 0) {
        result.add(this[index]);
      }
    }
return result;
  }
}
```

Trying it in an example:

```
List<String> list = ["banana", "cherry","apple", "pear","kiwi"];
print(list.elementsEveryN(2)); // [banana, pear]
```